# Why HTTP Post to Url does not passing value of input?

Tags: http, url, post

Got GIS-R10 (Guest Internet Gateway) Device that is used to display guest wifi logon page before access to the internet is given. There is an option to create custom logon page based on HTML which I did and also there is an option to use POST.PHP file to add guest entered values like name and email to database (mysql).

Now in the file called login.html to display logon form you have to include in the code `<!--LOGIN-->` tag. as bellow:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="login_table" align="center">
<tbody><tr>
<td class="uni_01" style="border-bottom:1px #cccccc solid;">
<!--LOGIN-->
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Then I did select an option on the device admin page to redirect data to `myserver.com/post.php` and unfortunately row in data base is added but empty email and name field received.

When the option "HTTP POST TO URL" is selected with my post.php file than on index of the logon page script is adding code:

```
<!--include(myserver/post.php);-->
```

and form added by `<!--LOGIN-->` tag is

```
<form method="post" name="registered" onsubmit="return validateRegistered()">
            <input type="hidden" name="url" value="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=219472">
            <input type="hidden" name="ip" value="192.168.96.10">
            <input type="hidden" name="code" value="d">
            <br><br>
            <table cellpadding="4" border="0">

                <tbody><tr><td>Name: </td><td><input type="text" name="data1" style="width: 120px"></td></tr>

                <tr><td>Email: </td><td><input type="text" name="data2" style="width: 120px"></td></tr>

                <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Connect" style="font: 12px arial, helvetica, sans-serif"></td></tr>
            </tbody></table>
            <br>
            You must agree to our <a href="/disclaimer.cgi" target="_blank" id="termslink"><u>terms and conditions</u></a> to use this service.    
            </form>
```

Finally in the post.php file I do use:

```
$name=$_POST['data1'];
$email=$_POST['data2'];
```

to add data1 and data2 value to my database and receive empty value.

Any idea or point in to right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: what does the validateRegistered() function?

Comment: also you should add the proper ending tag /> to the input fields, /> instead of >

Comment: @Sepulture It does check if email is not empty or include @ in value

Input fields are done automaticaly by script, you have no access to this, you just can display them by `<!--LOGIN-->` code

Comment: can you post the contents of the validateRegistered() function?

Comment: sure `<script type="text/javascript">
     function validateRegistered() {

      var data = document.forms["registered"]["data1"];
      if ( data.value == null || data.value == "" ) {
       alert("Box cannot be empty");
       data.focus();
       return false;
      }

      var data = document.forms["registered"]["data2"];
      if ( data.value == null || data.value == "" ) {
       alert("Box cannot be empty");
       data.focus();
       return false;
      }

      return true;
     }
    </script>`

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the action-attribute of the form-element, if you wan't to submit the form to a .php-file:

```
<form action="post.php" method="post" name="registered" onsubmit="return validateRegistered()">
```

If the request is dispatched to your .php file, you can also try to use $_GET or $_REQUEST instead of $_POST

Edit:
please try this again:

```
<?php 

print_r($_REQUEST);
exit;

// here MySQL db connector 

$primarykey1 = $_REQUEST['data1']; 
$primarykey2 = $_REQUEST['data2']; 

...
```

if the variables are not in the $_REQUEST array, you have to contact the customer service, I don't see any mistakes.

Also note: please escape the data before saving it into the database, use mysql_real_escape_string($primarykey1) in your case, or better use the mysql PDO abstraction layer

Comment: I dont think you get this, I can not edit any field in `<form></form>` this form is added trough `<!--LOGIN-->` tag that you have to add to your custom template of logon page.

Comment: how do you submit the form to the post.php? Is there any other JavaScript which submits the form?

Comment: I believe there must be something in the background as on admin page you can set lots of options also select option of "Http post to url" where than you give your adres of post.php file for ex. myserver.com/post.php and it does work because every time I click on connect than record is added to the data base with new id but no name or email values passed to those.

Comment: Neither $primarykey1 = $_REQUEST['data1'];  $primarykey1 = $_GET['data1']; isn't working in post.php file.

Comment: was there an example included? - I read something about a login.zip file. However, can you print_r($_REQUEST); maybe they saved the variables somewhere else

Comment: [http://www.wispzone.co.uk/pages/collecting-email-addresses-from-hotspot-users] that is their explenation of collecting email adress folow by manual [http://www.guest-internet.com/manual/manual.pdf] PAGE 82 and 89 then examples here [http://www.guest-internet.com/loginpages/] basing on examples I have done my login.html file.

Comment: do a print_r($_REQUEST); if it's not there, then you have to contact the customer service. They can also provide you an example .php file.

Comment: are you sure that $_POST['data1'] is empty? How do you save it in the database?

Comment: print_r($_REQUEST); in the .php-file. maybe you have to add exit; statement after print_r

Comment: So I have added this to post.php file however when I physically typed adress to this file in browser than I did get this `Array ( ) New record created successfully` and again id is added to the database but name and email empty.

Comment: no, you have to submit the form via the login page, otherwise there is no post request, it's just a normal get request without parameters

Comment: How do you want me to then display array? if Im not redirected to post file? Im redirected to the adres specified in admin page not post.php as that is happening in the background?

Comment: yes that's ok, just put this in the php-file: print_r($_REQUEST); exit; and submit the login form

Comment: As Im sayig it does not give me any data? as Im redirected straight away to the primary website of the business as I did specified this in options of the device.

Comment: can you post the complete php-file (but remove all passwords etc)?

Comment: `<?php
print_r($_REQUEST);

here MySQL db connector

$primarykey1 = $_REQUEST['data1'];
$primarykey2 = $_REQUEST['data2'];
 
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "INSERT INTO rghotel (id, date, name, email)
VALUES (NULL, 'test', '$primarykey1', '$primarykey2')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Added";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

?>`

Comment: I have updated my answer - did you tried it with the exit statement?

Comment: So they have go back to me from support `You should be able to access the data from the automatically populated $_POST variable,
This should be possible with a
 var_dump($_POST);
or similar You can then use this information as you wish to add to your database.` so than in my `post.php` file do I use simply $primarykey2 = $_var_dump['data2']; ? or var_dump is all of the values posted in form and than I have to format this result to data1 and data2?

Comment: no, var_dump is basically the same as print_r, it just prints the contents of a variable: e.g. var_dump($_POST); prints all post variables. Try it with the exit statement i have postet

Comment: `Array ( ) New record created successfully` still nothing ;/ really anoying

Comment: `array(0) { }` thats all I get with `var_dump($_POST);
exit;`